# How to sort only odd integers from an array of both odd and even integers and only display the sorted odd integer?

Tags: java, arrays

here is the integer array given to me 111,77, 88, 44, 32, 11, 13, 25, 44 I need to sort & display only the odd elements of the array .

I had tried solving it using loops and if condition

i had  expected the output as 11 13 25 77 111

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class oddsortSolution {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n[] = { 111, 77, 88, 44, 32, 11, 13, 25, 44 };
        int i = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        while (i < n.length) {
            if (n[i] % 2 != 0) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < n.length; j++) {
                    if (n[j] > n[i]) {
                        n[j] = temp;
                        n[j] = n[i];
                        n[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(n[1]);

    }

}
```

Comment: Nothing more easier then `Arrays.stream(n)
        .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
        .sorted()
        .forEach(System.out::print);`

Comment: Your `i < n.length` in the `while` condition is always true..

Comment: The way you have worded the problem, you have two entirely unrelated issues at hand:

1. You have an array of mixed odd and even integers, you want to extract a new array from it, containing only the odd ones.
2. You have an array of integers (which all happen to be odd, but this is irrelevant now) and you want to sort them and display them.

Which part don't you know how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to keep track of your odd array size, increment it every time you find an odd value, determine if the value should be swapped somewhere in the existing array (ranging from 0 to oddArraySize) and insert it in the correct position. Try the following code,

```
public class oddsortSolution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n[] = { 111, 77, 88, 44, 32, 11, 13, 25, 44 };
        int oddArraySize = 0;        
        for (int i = 0;i < n.length; i++) {
            if (n[i] % 2 != 0) {
                oddArraySize++;
                for (int j = 0; j < oddArraySize; j++) {
                    if (j == oddArraySize - 1) {
                        n[j] = n[i];
                    } else if (n[j] > n[i]) {
                        int temp = n[j];
                        n[j] = n[i];
                        n[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int[] oddArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(n, 0, oddArraySize);
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( oddArray ));
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the same problem, infinite loop because `i < n.length` is always true because you don't change the value of `i`...

Comment: Can you please explain what was your logic after this statement brother  for (int j = 0; j < oddArraySize; j++) .....

Comment: After we increment the `oddArraySize`, we know that we have an odd value at index `i`. Now, we compare this odd value with all the other (odd) values in the range `[0,oddArraySize]`, if any value in that range (ie. `n[j]`) is greater than `n[i]`, then we swap those two values. When we reach the end (ie. `oddArraySize`), We directly assign the odd value there. Once all of this is completed, we copy only the odd array part into a new `oddArray`.